# react-native run-android fails from terminal

Tags: react-native

D:\ReactNative\AwesomeProject>react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 863 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...
:ReactNative:Cannot run program "npx": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
:ReactNative:Automatic import of native modules failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'D:\ReactNative\AwesomeProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 169
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

  > Cannot invoke method getErrorStream() on null object
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'D:\ReactNative\AwesomeProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 169
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

  > Cannot invoke method getErrorStream() on null object
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:621:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:639:15)
at runOnAllDevices (D:\ReactNative\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Your question consists of error output with no description. Please improve this question by adding an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: the question is completely obvious

Comment: @chandrakant Chaturvedi please review my answer.

Answer (score 20):

For me the problem was over this cli:

```
@react-native-community/cli-platform-android
```

The problematic version:

```
3.0.0-alpha.7
```

Just run this to install the latest stable release:

```
npm i @react-native-community/cli-platform-android@2.9.0
```

UPDATE 2020:

if this workaround doesn't work now, take a look over this link to use the latest version from the repo, and look the version of your cli to compare and use the correct one:

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android
```

Comment: woah, i was searching for an hour to realize react native's own setup has a bad package version!? thanks for this

Comment: @zackify yeah, for me was more than an hour, i'm glad it is help you.

Comment: @zackify is this a core library dependency?

Comment: Thank you. That's great to follow your tips

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem on linux. All I had to do was just installing npx globally to my machine, that's all.

`sudo npm install -g npx`

This happens because of lines 155 and 159 in native_modules.gradle:

`def command = "${npx} --quiet react-native config"`

...

`cmdProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)`

It tries to execute the command but command npx is not found.

Answer (score 2):

I have copied and replaced this file from the older project and it did the trick for now.

node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle'

Answer (score 2):

For me, I had not closed a tag in my AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and to get it sorted you have downgrade your react-native version or create project with custom react-native version .
react-native init AwesomeProject --version X.XX.X
react-native init myfirstProject --version 0.60.0
 (from official react native documentation) .
 https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started
Now you can either run it directly from Command line or open Android studio and then open Android folder of react native app in that ( it will sync gradles files and build ).

Answer (score 0):

A temporary fix was suggested on github about making changes to your **native_modules.gradle** file. You need to go to that file location **YourProjectDir\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle** and at line 153, change `npx --quiet react-native config` to `npx.cmd --quiet react-native config`.

[Original answer](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/795#issuecomment-542517189)

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste package.json and native_modules.gradle https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/tree/master/packages/platform-android

Comment: Try to provide a short hint about your answer. so that it will reach very soon. link wont impress

Answer (score 0):

In Windows

Set environment variable

System Variable > Path > C:\Users\ **ankit**\ .WebStorm2019.3\config\node\node-v12.13.1-win-x64

Answer (score 0):

For solove this preblem first use this command

```
yarn install
```

then,

```
npx react-native start
```

and ,

```
npx react-native run-android
```